# Deleting from a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to, unobtrusive-javascript

I have setup a admin namespace in order to access models in the admin area: `/admin/pages`

However i have the following problem
i cant get the delete function to work under `Admin::PageController` for example or any of my models.

Does anyone know how to do this.
I have the following:

Admin::PageController I have the following

```
def destroy
   @page = Page.find(params[:id])
   @page.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to admin_pages_url }
     format.json { head :ok }
   end
end
```

Then on my page index file where i want a link to delete the record i have the following: (/admin/pages)

```
<%=link_to admin_page_path(page), :class => 'ico del' do %>
  <%='Delete'%>
<% end %>
```

Does not seem to work. Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

you have missed :method option in link_to call

```
 link_to 'Delete', admin_page_path, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

or

```
<%=link_to admin_page_path(page), :class => 'ico del',:method => :delete do %>
  <%='Delete'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: First Option brings up Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/pages"}

Secound option just brings up the show method and shows the records details

Comment: @Naveed And you have missed passing in the `page` object so it knows which object to delete.....

Comment: @iWasRobbed No i did it intentionally,by convention if current action is show `admin_page_path` will get id from params and pass it to `url_for` helper,so lets say if you hit admin/pages/2 calling `admin_page_path` will generate /admin/pages/2 BUT its dangerous because now `admin_people_path` will also generate admin/people/2 :)

Comment: @user964900 check if you have include rails.js in your template

Answer (score 0):

The `link_to` helper defaults to a `GET` request unless you specify additional attributes to tell it how you want it to be handled.

In this case, you need to set some extra arguments:

```
<%=link_to "Delete", admin_page_path(page), :class => "ico del", :remote => true, :method => :delete %>
```

What actually happens in the background is the [Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) (unobtrusive javascript adapter) captures the click event and sends the request via AJAX.  So you should see it hit your server with a `POST` (but it passes in `_method => delete` as well) to delete the object.

I'm also assuming you have your routes set up correctly.  Something like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :pages
end
```

Comment: Hi yes namespace is correct, also not working. it is brings up the show method also

Comment: Ok if i change link_to to button_to it works but does not look nice but works

Comment: The reason why `button_to` works is because it generates a form with a submit button for you (which means it's not submitting it via AJAX).  So the problem is, you probably don't have jQuery or the Rails UJS jQuery adapter installed.  Make sure you follow the instructions (for Rails 3.1 which I assume you are on): https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#readme